# Pearson Correlation Return nan correlation

Tags: seaborn, heatmap, nan, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a Dataframe without missing value. When I try to find correlation between columns, the sns.heatmap gives me empty correlation.

```
corr = dfno.corr()   
sns.heatmap(corr, annot= True)
```

[image]

I got this result. What is the reason of this result?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may have several constant columns:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4))
df.loc[:,1] = 1

corr = df.corr()
```

Then `corr` is:

```
          0   1         2         3
0  1.000000 NaN  0.190780  0.026337
1       NaN NaN       NaN       NaN
2  0.190780 NaN  1.000000  0.447265
3  0.026337 NaN  0.447265  1.000000
```

And

```
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)
```

gives:

[image]